# on scroll list background change in android

Tags: android, listview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                System.out.println("getView position " + position);

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.groupitem, null);

                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textitem);
                holder.btn = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.button1);
                holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Clickable button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.groupheader, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(position==1){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celltop);
            }
        else if (position>1 && position!=1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellcenter);
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

when started its backgroung is correct.but when i scroll list down and come back again to top its background changes.for example celltop background is on top which is heading.i just want to set backgroung for items

Comment: check at `if(position==1){` here you are missing `position==0`?? May be it is the problem

Comment: i have a list with section.in header no background needed but on section i need a background.In section row 1 background is different to 2nd.in simple i want to make sections edges curves not whole list

Comment: if i use postion 0 then it will set background for header

Comment: this is like an array of array.and want to display in list.first array index value is header and on this index all values are section

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : 
Don't set the background of view based on position, because once you scroll, the position of the UI view is changed. try to set tag for view and set background for the view with tag as condition.
This is your custom adapter's `Overrided getView` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
TextView description = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.description);
description.setTag(myArrayList.get(position).get("hashmamkey")); 
// Where myArrayList is ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

// Now make a condition  
if((HashMap<String,String>) description.getTag().equals("value")){
// Do Your change background for view Work Here
}


}
```

Comment: i cant understand i am on starter level will u help me in code